# Confusion about malloc and calloc function in C

Tags: c, function, malloc, void, calloc

Declaration of `malloc` function:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Here, `malloc` returns **void pointer**. So, A `void` function returns nothing, then

**Why we assign malloc(function call) value to pointer?**

For example:

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof (*ptr));
^^^
```

What does return value holds from `malloc()`???

Comment: `void` is *nothing*, but a *pointer* to `void` is still a pointer, it's just unspecified what kind of data it points to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was probably an unfortunate choice on the part of language designers, but they decided to reuse `void` for their `void*` construct, which nearly reverses its meaning: while `void` means "returns nothing", `void*` means "return a pointer to anything."

Essentially, `void*` is a pointer to an unspecified object. It must be converted to a pointer to a specific type before you dereference it. That is precisely the kind of pointer returned by `malloc` or `calloc`.

Answer (score 2):

void and void* are different. 
void means nohting but void* can be anything.
A pointer of void (void*)  can be casted into any other pointers.

Why malloc() return void*?

It means malloc allocated a memory buffer for you and you can use it to store anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to get confused by the white space. In C, you should read declarations this way:

`int *i;` is to be read as - the variable `*i` which gives an int *or* the variable `i` which is a pointer to an int. Same goes for functions. Something like `void *fun()` means `fun` is a function which returns a pointer to a `void`. Check [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/charstarws.html) for a more complete answer.

Comment: You mean `int *fun()`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, my bad. Corrected.